# How do I set heatmap colors with min and max values when the colorpalette is diverging?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I would like to set the max and min values of the scale of my color palette. In the example below I would like the scale of the color palette to go from -10 to 50 as if it was a sequential colormap.  I don't really care to highlight where the numbers cross the "zero line."

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  
import seaborn as sns

index = np.arange(0, 50)
data = np.random.uniform(low=-10, high=100, size=(50,50))
dft = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=index, data=data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([.905, 0.125, .05, 0.755])
ax = sns.heatmap(dft, linewidths=.5, cmap=cm.YlGnBu, cbar_kws={'label': 'label'},
                 ax=ax, square=True, cbar_ax=cbar_ax, center=55)
plt.show()
```

However if I do:

```
ax = sns.heatmap(dft, linewidths=.5, cmap=cm.YlGnBu, cbar_kws={'label': 'label'},
                 ax=ax, square=True, cbar_ax=cbar_ax, vmax=50, vmin=-10)
```

The color palette goes from -50 to 50, and `vmin=-10` is ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) (for **vmin, vmax**),

> When a diverging dataset is inferred, one of these values may be ignored.

You should use the `center` argument to specify the value at which to center the colormap, in conjunction with one of `vmax` or `vmin` to specify a limit.

```
vmin, vmax = -10, 50
sns.heatmap(..., center=(vmin + vmax) / 2., vmax=vmax)
```